# JTable TableColumn - no property change for modelIndex when dragging columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

I need to detect when the user reorders columns of a `JTable`, in order to persist and restore that information. According to JavaDocs, it should be sufficient to add a `propertyChangeListener` to the table columns, like

```java
    JTable t = ...;
    TableColumn keysColumn   = t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    TableColumn valuesColumn = t.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    keysColumn.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener {
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        System.out.println("PROPERTY: " + e.getPropertyName());
      }
    });
```

However, while I receive updates for `width` and `preferredWidth`, reordering the columns does not fire anything observable here. I am expecting to see an update of `modelIndex`. Doing anything wrong?

OpenJDK 11 on Linux, tried different look and feels.

Answer (score 1):

So the `modelIndex` of a `TableColumn` never changes, and thus no property changes. To observe the movement, one has to listen to the `TableColumnModel` for `columnMoved` and filter for `e.getFromIndex != e.getToIndex` which are view indices, then map those back to model indices. "so simple" :-/

Here in Scala

```scala
val tcm = t.getColumnModel

tcm.addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener {
  private def mkMap() = Seq.tabulate(t.getColumnCount)(t.convertColumnIndexToModel)

  private var viewToModel = mkMap()

  override def columnMoved(e: TableColumnModelEvent): Unit = {
    val viewFrom  = e.getFromIndex
    val viewTo    = e.getToIndex
    if (viewFrom != viewTo) {
      val modelFrom = viewToModel(viewFrom)
      val modelTo   = viewToModel(viewTo  )
      println(s"columnMoved: drag column $modelFrom from pos $viewFrom to $viewTo")
      viewToModel = mkMap()
      assert (viewToModel(viewTo) == modelFrom)
    }
  }

  override def columnAdded            (e: TableColumnModelEvent ): Unit = ()
  override def columnRemoved          (e: TableColumnModelEvent ): Unit = ()
  override def columnMarginChanged    (e: ChangeEvent           ): Unit = ()
  override def columnSelectionChanged (e: ListSelectionEvent    ): Unit = ()
})
```